# How to return the wrong fruit if it is the first item in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently working through the precourse for a coding bootcamp and I am struggling with this question. There are 7 conditions I have to meet and I am consistently failing one no matter what I try. I'll post the question, my answer and the conditions.

**Question**

Find the wrong way fruit
This function takes an array of fruit (orchard) in the format:

['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'elppa', 'apple']
The fruit will all be the 'right way round' apart from 1 fruit!

Your function should return its index position. So in this example, the function should return 4.

Note: The fruit will not always be apple, but it will always be an orchard of the same kind of fruit.

findWrongWayFruit(['apple', 'apple', 'elppa']) // returns 2

findWrongWayFruit(['apple', 'elppa', 'apple']) // returns 1

findWrongWayFruit(['banana', 'ananab', 'banana', 'banana']) // returns 1

findWrongWayFruit(['apple', 'elppa']) // returns 0 as we can't tell which one is the right way round

**Answer**

```
    function findWrongWayFruit(orchard) {
  const firstFruit = orchard[0];
  if (orchard.length < 3) {
    return 0; // Return 0 if the orchard length is less than 3
  }
  
  for (let i = 1; i < orchard.length; i++) {
    if (firstFruit !== orchard[i]) {
      return i; // Return the index of the wrong-way fruit
    }
  }
}
```

**Conditions**

6 Passing
1 Failing

should be a function

```
✓  Well done!
```

should return a number

```
✓  Well done!
```

should return 0 when passed an array length smaller than 3

```
✓  Well done!
```

should return the correct index when the wrong-way fruit is in the middle of the array

```
✓  Well done!
```

should return the correct index when the wrong-way fruit is at start

✕ AssertionError: expected 1 to equal +0

should return the correct index when the wrong-way fruit is at the end

```
✓  Well done!
```

should return the correct index when the wrong-way fruit is at any other random position

```
✓  Well done!
```

Comment: The condition `if (firstFruit !== orchard[i]) {` is not correct. First, you have to find out the correct fruit name. Then, you have to find the wrong fruit name with something like `if (correctFruit !== orchard[i]) {`. One way to find the correct fruit name is to iterate over the array and count occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate the array and compare the current and previous items
2. If the first items aren't the same, check the third item to avoid false positives at the start:

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'elppa', 'apple'];


function findIdx(fruits){
  
  if(fruits.length < 3) return -1;
  
  for(let i = 1; i < fruits.length; i++){
    if(fruits[i] !== fruits[i-1]){
      return i > 1 ? i : fruits[0] === fruits[2] ? 1 : 0;
    }
  }
  
  return -1;
}
console.log(findIdx(['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'elppa', 'apple']));
console.log(findIdx(['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'elppa']));
console.log(findIdx(['elppa', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple']));
console.log(findIdx(['apple', 'elppa', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple']));
console.log(findIdx(['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple']));
console.log(findIdx(['apple', 'elppa']));
```